# Jupyter Notebooks incorrectly calculating numpy conjugation to a power

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I happened upon some error in my Jupyter Notebook that I can't explain. I have the following code.

```
import numpy as np
c = 100
c_conj = np.conjugate(c)
print(c == c_conj)
print(c**5 == c_conj**5)
```

Resulting in the output

```
True
False
```

I get the same result for JupyterLite (the online Jupyter Notebook software). Alternatively, if I run the same code on any other platform (e.g. Google Collab), I get the output

```
True
True
```

Is this user error? Is there a way to explain this?

Comment: When you see a comparison returning something unexpected, don't forget to print both sides of the comparison to see the actual values!

Comment: Printing types and values would help. What is `type(c_conj)`? And what are the np versions?

Comment: I'd caution against using JupyterLite as your online Jupyter software. It still has some quirks and is clearly indicated as **experimental**. For real comparison, you can use a typical, full python kernel in Jupyter by going [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements) and pressing 'launch binder' to get a temporary session on remote machine served by MyBinder. Presently it will open into JupyterLab, and you can switch to classic interface from under the 'Help' menu item on the File menubar: '`Help`' > '`Launch Classic Notebook`'. You code gives `True` & `True` there.

Comment: Just to clarify, JupyterLite is technically not running 'online'.  (Your description: "JupyterLite (the online Jupyter Notebook software)".) The JupyterLite files are served to your browser and then the computation is done locally inside your browser using web assembly (WASM). The MyBinder-served served offerings are running remotely in the cloud and served to your local browser, and so would be closer to an 'online software' version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`numpy.conjugate(100)` returns a `numpy.int_` instance, not a plain Python `int`. `numpy.int_` corresponds to C `long`. On the platforms where the comparison evaluated to `False`, C `long` is 32 bits, and the `c_conj**5` computation overflowed.